# Как отсортировать и взять топ записей в XSLT?

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

Есть набор строк. Необходимо его отсортировать по полю `Count`, затем по полю `LastSeen` и взять Топ 20 из этого списка с помощью `xslt`.
Сортирую и вывожу с помощью кода ниже, а как взять только топ?

```
<xsl:for-each select="//Info">
  <xsl:sort order="descending" select="Count" />
  <xsl:sort order="descending" select="LastSeen" />
  <tr>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="."></xsl:apply-templates>
  </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сохраните результат сортировки в переменную, а потом возьмите топ из нее:

```
<xsl:variable name="infos">
  <xsl:for-each select="//Info">
    <xsl:sort order="descending" select="Count" />
    <xsl:sort order="descending" select="LastSeen" />
    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($infos)/Info[position() &lt;= 20]">
  <tr>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="." />
  </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Для того, чтобы такое преобразование работало в XSLT 1й версии, надо в корень добавить регистрацию префикса `xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"`. Или используйте вместо него префикс `msxsl`, который добавляется студией по умолчанию.

В случае XSLT 2й версии, функция `node-set` не нужна и можно обращаться к переменной напрямую.

Comment: Спасибо, а поясните, пожалуйста, вот эту часть кода:  

`exsl:node-set($temp)/Info` как здесь передается имя переменной?

Comment: Переменная - это то, что после знака доллара. Извиняюсь, что у меня была ошибка в ее имени )

Comment: Спасибо :) А то я смотрю, вроде бы после доллара должно быть имя переменной, а вызов идет другого имени)